# Restoring Django request object in graphene

Tags: django, api, graphql, graphene-django

I'm using `graphene-django` to make an `API`, I don't have access to the `request object` anymore. I want a global variable to `access the logged in user in any file`.

I want to implement this solution and I want to know if it's unnecessary or the right way.

```
    class user:
        __instance = None
        def __new__(cls, username, id, **_ignored):
            if cls.__instance is None:
                cls.__instance = object.__new__(cls)
                cls.__instance.username = username
                cls.__instance.id = id
            return cls.__instance
```

Also opened to your solutions. Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with using `info.context.user` that's passed for all query?

Comment: info.context is only available in schema files. How will I have access to it in utils.py if you know?